# Union of two or more lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a number of lists (only 3 shown here)

```
 List1 = {{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
 List2 = {{1, 2, 4, 8, 7}, {1, 2, 9, 10}};
 List3 = {{9, 11, 1}, {1, 9, 11, 13}, {1, 9, 12}, {1, 9, 14}};
```

I want to combine these lists in the following way: Union the last element of List1 with each element of List2, and add it to the end of List1, then Union the last element of List2 to all the elements of List3 and add them to the end of List1.

Producing

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 
 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 
 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
 13}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}}
```

I should mention, the numbers are random, although here it appears as consecutive at some places.

#### Edit

With @ciao's help, I have the solution

```
Union@FoldList[Union, Join[List1, List2, List3]]
```

However, it seems to drop repeated elements as it appears in List3.

#### Edit 2

Fidgeting around for a bit, I realized on dropping the outer Union, the problem is solved.

```
FoldList[Union, Join[List1, List2, List3]]
```

Comment: You could have devised a perhaps shorter and more clear example!

Comment: Your output does not match what you describe. `r1 = Union[list1[[-1]], #] & /@ list2;
r2 = Union[list2[[-1]], #] & /@ list3;
r3 = {r1, r2}`

Comment: `Union@FoldList[Union, Join[list1, list2, list3]]` produces the output shown... but that's about as far as I'm willing to decode the OP - perhaps a clearer example/explanation is warranted?

Comment: @Nasser Yes, you are right. My bad. I have fixed the issue.

Comment: @ciao Sorry about that, I have fixed the problem. You have the right solution! Thanks!

Comment: @ciao Is there a way to modify your code so that it doesn't truncates identical elements in the list? See edited version.

Comment: @HuShu: +1 on figuring out your question to me...

Comment: You should self-answer in that case,  and preferably shorten down your example to make it more accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works

```
   FoldList[Union, Join[List1, List2, List3]]
```